# Разный набор полей для разных функций

Tags: c#, сериализация, newtonsoft.json

Есть две функции, которые обращаются к API. Одна с методом `POST`, вторая - `PATCH`.

Для обеих используется один класс, который включает поля

```cs
public class Attribute
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string attribute_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string attribute_value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Не обращайте внимание на нейминг, я вот такой ленивый человек и просто забил на это пока.

При отправке данных в виде `json` с методом `POST` я просто собираю данные и устанавливаю контент

```cs
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attribute); // attribute - объект класса Attribute
```

Для обновления записи я хочу использовать тот же самый класс, но хочу исключить поле `attribute_value` и отправлять только `value` и `attribute_name`. Поскольку я получаю объект со всеми полями, я не могу установить свойство `NullValueHandling.Ignore`, поскольку оно точно будет не нулевым. Я не могу использовать `[JsonIgnore]`, поскольку этот же самый класс используется для метода `POST`.

Есть готовый объект, можно ли указать поле класса, которое я хочу не включать в `json` при сериализации? Удалить из объекта?

Comment: Я бы просто создал новый класс (можно анонимный) без этого свойства. | А так есть [Conditional Property Serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/conditionalproperties.htm)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я привел в пример только три поля, в реальном мире класс состоит из порядка 30 полей со связями. Переписывать очень трудоемко получится. Не хочется простыню набирать=)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov идея/вопрос: сработает если я поля буду обнулять в объекте, а потом сериализировать? и следовательно использовать `NullValueHandling.Ignore`. Пойду попробую, если антипаттерн, скажите мне об этом)

Comment: А что мешает сделать составной класс, из нескольких классов? Просто разбейте все на несколько классов, унаследуйте как надо, и дальше используйте там, где надо те классы, которые содержат нужные свойства.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил пока так

сам класс

```cs
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class Attribute
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string attribute_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string? attribute_value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

и в логике обнуляю ненужное свойство

```cs
attribute.attribute_value = null;
var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attribute);
```

На выходе имеем `json` без ненужной пары ключ:значение.

Кидайте помидорами, если такое решение не верно.

Comment: для пет проекта нормас, для прода, который потом другие люди будут годами поддерживать - ну такое )

Comment: это прод, пэт проекты закончились лет много тому назад. Для меня c# новое

Comment: да тут дело не в C#, тут больше в том, хочешь ли ты использовать разные модели для разных запросов или хочешь стрельнуть в ногу. Сегодня одно поле надо скрыть, завтра надо будет 10 в одном случае добавить полей, и 5 в другом случае убрать. Если прогер будет мимикрировать тот же подход, что здесь, то не успеешь обернуться, как в коде будет лапша из if-else